# SSRS 2005 export to PDF never ends

Tags: pdf, service, reporting-services, export, reporting

I have a case where the Reporting Services takes an infinite amount of time to export to PDF for huge number of pages; around 1600 page.

Exporting to excel works fine for this amount of pages, but to pdf, it does not. I tried to increase the virtual memory, it still did not work.

I am using Reporting Services 2005. Would upgrading to a newer version fix the problem? What alternatives do I have (even if upgrading is a solution, since my client is not ready to upgrade).

It’s worth noting that the server used by my client has very good specs in terms of memory, processor…

Thank you.
Roy Helayel

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services. SQL Server 2008 introduced much better performance for generating large reports (see [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e6b8c870-55da-4041-952a-c83a70c5c405)). If generating large reports to PDF is a requirement for your client then they should consider upgrading to a newer version of SQL Server.